# Using keyboard events in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, keyboard

I'm trying to write a simple program in AS3 Non- OOP (I'm coding directly to the timeline) but my function "choices" isn't being called like it should. In fact it's not being called at all and I receive no compiler error. Here's my code:

```
//Black jack game
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,talk);

stop();
var yourHand1:Number = 0;
var cHand1:Number = 0;
var yourHand2:Number = 0;
var cHand2:Number = 0;

function talk(e:Event){

    if(yourHand1 < 3){
        yourHand1 +1;
    }
    if(cHand1 < 3){
        cHand1 +1;
    }
    cHand1 = 1+Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
    yourHand1 = 1+Math.floor(Math.random()* 11);
    trace(cHand1);  
    trace(yourHand1);
    cHand.text = cHand1.toString();
    yourHand.text = yourHand1.toString();
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, talk);
    //choices();
}

addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,choices);

function choices(event:KeyboardEvent){
    trace("Would you like to hit or stay?");
    trace("Press left arrow to hit, space bar to stay");
    if(event.charCode == 65){
        trace("You have chosen to stay");
    }
    if(event.charCode == 66){
        letsDoItAllAgain();
    }
}


function letsDoItAllAgain(){

    if(yourHand2 <= 2){
        yourHand2 +2;
    }
    if(cHand2 <= 2){
        cHand2 +2;
    }
    cHand2 = 1+Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
    yourHand2 = 1+Math.floor(Math.random()* 11);
    trace(cHand2);  
    trace(yourHand2);
    cHand.text = (cHand2 + cHand1).toString();
    yourHand.text = (yourHand1 + cHand2).toString();
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, letsDoItAllAgain);
}
```

Comment: simple program in AS3 Non- OOP, this is incorrect statement, as3 is OOP language even on the time line.

Comment: Does it work if you call it directly? If so then it can be concluded that the `KEY_DOWN` event isn't firing and that will be the focus of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add eventListener on stage.

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,choices);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition Pan says:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,choices);
```

Is important to know that you can lose the focus of your main window.
I have some similar in my project (too in the timeline), and i have to call regularly this (when i know that the focus can be lost):

```
stage.focus = stage;
```